# jQuery change content of div with button press ( include() )

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, button, include

I need some basic help, I cant find my solution :(

I try to have menu with some buttons on the left side (`menu_kneeboard`). If you click something, it would open another php file with the `include()` function in the `content_kneeboard` section. How do I do it? If I use the `.text` statement (? attribute?) it works and it will show "IT WORKS!" in the `content_kneeboard` `div`. 
But how could I make it working while using `<?php include("map.php"); ?>` as action?

I tried `.html(<?php include("map.php"); ?>)` but it does not seem to work. `.php` does not seem to excist.

```
        <div class="menu_kneeboard">
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function() {
                $("button").click(function() {
                    $(".content_kneeboard").text("IT WORKS!");
                })
            });

        </script>
        <button>click</button>
    </div>
    <div class="content_kneeboard">
        <p>old content</p>
    </div>
```

Thank you for your help! :)

Comment: Are you wanting to open a modal or redirect to map.php or just replace .content_kneeboard with map.php?

Comment: replace .content_kneeboard with map.php :)

Comment: You could include all your php files and add  a class with the css property `display: none;` to them and when pressing the button remove this class for the file you want to be shown and add it to the file that has been shown

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what content is in map.php, so this may not be the best solution if it's a lot of markup, but you can put the markup directly in the tag:

```
$("button").click(function() {
    $(".content_kneeboard").empty(); //if there are other elements in this div you want to preserve, keep in mind this will remove those too.
    $(".content_kneeboard").html('<div id="map_content"></div>');
});
```

Another option would be to include the php on the initial page load but set `display:none;`, and then in your button click you could do something like (jquery):

```
$("#map_content").fadeIn('fast');
```

or with js:

```
document.getElementById(map_content).style.display = 'block';
```

it would largely depend on what exactly the content of map.php is. If we knew more about the implementation it might yield you better results in terms of answers.

I will add that if its any significant amount of markup, more than a couple of divs, I'd probably opt to include the php on the initial page load as hidden, and then show it when the button is clicked. That's generally how I handle this sort of thing.

If you need to know more specifically how to implement that, let me know and I can add to this answer.

Comment: There is very much text in map.php and - important - it will not only be map.php. There will be many buttons on the left side, which will change the content in the middle (content_kneeboard).

So the idea to just dont display them is the best I guess. But isnt there a simple solution to just include the main.php (and other files on button click) with the <?php include("kneeboard/subpage/subpage_map.php"); ?> "command"?

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/FylcS6L

This is how it looks right now.
Each button on the left shoud change the content in the middle (where the map is right know). BUT the user can change his used plane and map in some settings, so even for the checklists there are nearly 30 different php files (Checklists) I want to load into the content area (depends on the chosen plane in the settings).

Comment: Ahh, I saw “kneeboard” and wondered if it was aviation related. The way I would do it would be to use an Ajax request on button click to fetch the contents of map.php or whatever other content needs to be loaded, and then echo the content back in the Ajax response where you’d then sub out the content using JavaScript. I can add an example later if need be, but google around for Ajax requests. There are plenty of examples.

Comment: Yeah aviation related :D. Oh shit - sounds complicated :-O! I will look into it, thank you very much!

Comment: It’s not too bad once you get the feel for it and it will open up a lot of possible use cases for your app. I use it a lot.

Comment: I just realised that my code in the question works. But .. not with .html but with .load (after searching for Ajax request on google). LOL. Thank you very much :D